# How to have MessageListener fire when exception is thrown under v8::TryCatch block

Tags: javascript, v8, embedded-v8

I would like to have generalized uncaught exception handling code live in one place.  I accomplish this by using `v8::Isolate::AddMessageListenerWithErrorLevel`.  One issue with this I have noticed though is, the message listener will never fire when an exception occurs under a `v8::TryCatch`.  Calling `v8::TryCatch::ReThrow` does not seem to make a difference.

My question is, is it possible to have the exception get sent to the message listener somehow?  I would like to have a `v8::TryCatch` in this particular location, in order to inspect errors that happen there myself, and send them to separate internal logging, and at the same time, I want to use the message listener to send the error to another location (this one is client facing).

My minimum repro example is below (created by modifying the `hello-world.cc` example file).

```
void MessageHandler(v8::Local<v8::Message> message, v8::Local<v8::Value> data) {
  printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  // Initialize V8.
  v8::V8::InitializeICUDefaultLocation(argv[0]);
  v8::V8::InitializeExternalStartupData(argv[0]);
  std::unique_ptr<v8::Platform> platform = v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform();
  v8::V8::InitializePlatform(platform.get());
  v8::V8::Initialize();

  // Create a new Isolate and make it the current one.
  v8::Isolate::CreateParams create_params;
  create_params.array_buffer_allocator =
      v8::ArrayBuffer::Allocator::NewDefaultAllocator();
  v8::Isolate* isolate = v8::Isolate::New(create_params);

  isolate->AddMessageListenerWithErrorLevel(
      MessageHandler,
      v8::Isolate::kMessageError | v8::Isolate::kMessageWarning |
          v8::Isolate::kMessageInfo | v8::Isolate::kMessageDebug |
          v8::Isolate::kMessageLog);

  {
    v8::Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate);

    // Create a stack-allocated handle scope.
    v8::HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);

    // Create a new context.
    v8::Local<v8::Context> context = v8::Context::New(isolate);

    // Enter the context for compiling and running the hello world script.
    v8::Context::Scope context_scope(context);

    // The message listener will fire if this is removed.
    v8::TryCatch try_catch(isolate);

    // Create a string containing the JavaScript source code.
    v8::Local<v8::String> source =
        v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "throw new Error()",
                                v8::NewStringType::kNormal)
            .ToLocalChecked();

    // Compile the source code.
    v8::Local<v8::Script> script =
        v8::Script::Compile(context, source).ToLocalChecked();

    // Run the script to get the result.
    v8::Local<v8::Value> result;
    if (script->Run(context).ToLocal(&result)) {
      // Convert the result to an UTF8 string and print it.
      v8::String::Utf8Value utf8(isolate, result);
      printf("Success: %s\n", *utf8);
    } else {
      printf("Error\n");
      // Calling this doesn't seem to make a difference.
      try_catch.ReThrow();
    }
  }

  // Dispose the isolate and tear down V8.
  isolate->Dispose();
  v8::V8::Dispose();
  v8::V8::ShutdownPlatform();
  delete create_params.array_buffer_allocator;
  return 0;
}
```

The message listener will be called only after removing the try catch.

Answer (score 0):

you need set verbose true by

```
try_catch.SetVerbose(true)
```